# android where to keep encrypted files

Tags: android, storage, encryption

I want to develop an application which lets user protect their files / folders . It is very much the same as existing apps where user can select the files to be hidden and those files can be accessed only from my app which is password protected.

I got enough resources about the encryption algorithm. 
Here my doubt is :

1. where should i keep my encrypted files. It should be within my app folder. But this folder if i create on phones internal storage, will that not lead to memory restrictions. My app let user to add images / videos or any other file to protection. If i keep the folder on the sd card, the questions are it will restrict app to be run on only mobiles with sd card . Also the content of sd card can be accessed by others ( i am right here ? )
2. The next doubt is that i see most of those apps i see if i remove protection it is restored in its previous folder. How is it achieved . Is it like keep mapping table an duse that to restore ?

Please help me with answers for my questions. Thanks a lot for your time and help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to my investigations of the same problem, there is no built-in encrypted storage in Android system. Hence, I'd recommend you following approach:

1. Encrypt file content with any algorithm. See [here(1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5432275/encrypted-storage-on-an-android-ipad), [here(2)](http://www.androidsnippets.com/encryptdecrypt-strings) and [here(3)](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0490__Security/UsingCipherOutputStream.htm).
2. Use [`MODE_PRIVATE`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#MODE_PRIVATE) when creating file with, for example, [`openFileOutput(String, int)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#openFileOutput%28java.lang.String,%20int%29)

Comment: thanks for the answers. MODE_PRIVATE doesnt apply for sd cards . So how do you manage encryption of files on sd card

Comment: You simply encrypt the content of the files. See the examples I've provided (the third one deals with `CipherOutputStream` and `CipherInputStream`).